CustomTkinter Label Widget corner_radius
I was making a expense tracker in python using the customtkinter library as my gui source.
The problem I encountered was that when setting up a label I wasnt able to give its corners a rounded edge here is the output image:
Output_Image
and the Code Here:
import customtkinter as ctk
import tkinter as tk

#Creating window and setting it up
root = ctk.CTk()
root.title("Expense Tracker")
root.geometry("1920x1080")
root._set_appearance_mode("dark")
ctk.set_default_color_theme("blue")
root.pack_propagate("False")

def home_page():
    #creating a frame for home page
    home_frame = ctk.CTkFrame(root,width = 1920, height = 1080)
    home_frame.pack()

    #Creating Labels for different section
    #Current in hand
    cih_label = ctk.CTkLabel(
        home_frame,width=390,height=142,bg_color="#ABABAB",text = "Currently In Hand:\n {}",font= ('Khula Light',44),corner_radius=5) #Even tried changing it to 500 
    cih_label.place(x = 20, y = 23)
home_page()
root.mainloop()

I tried to search across the net and youtube and found out that the method I am using is perfectly fine and even the og documentation states that the label widget supports corner_radius option

Set fg_color instead of bg_color and use corner_radius=30.

Your usage of the corner_radius parameter is fine and works. But, as acw1668 said, the bg_color parameter removes the label rounded corners. You should replace the bg_color parameter by fg_color.
The full code is now:
import customtkinter as ctk
import tkinter as tk

#Creating window and setting it up
root = ctk.CTk()
root.title("Expense Tracker")
root.geometry("1920x1080")
ctk.set_appearance_mode("dark")
ctk.set_default_color_theme("blue")
root.pack_propagate(False)

def home_page():
    #creating a frame for home page
    home_frame = ctk.CTkFrame(root,width = 1920, height = 1080)
    home_frame.pack()

    #Creating Labels for different section
    #Current in hand
    cih_label = ctk.CTkLabel(
        home_frame,width=390,height=142,fg_color="#ABABAB",text = "Currently In Hand:\n {}",font= ('Khula Light',44),corner_radius=5)
    cih_label.place(x = 20, y = 23)
home_page()
root.mainloop()

(I also corrected line 8 and 10 which weren't used properly)
To sum up, don't use bg_color in customtkinter ;)
Hope I helped you, have a nice day.
